# Googlespreedsheet query not working in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am currently working with google spreedsheet api v4. I wish to use query parameters to select only a row which has a certain Id in a cell. For example in I wish to select a row which matches the  passed parameters and will not bring the rest of data. It is just like php select * from db where id = "" ;(Let me make it simpler so people can understand,Look what I want to do is just like we use select query I only wish to select a row where SheetID value is equal to the parameter I have passed. I don't wish to return the whole json array just a singe record like we usually do with other db such as mysql etc ) But my code is not working. Here is my code

```
(async () => {
    await doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds);
        await doc.loadInfo();
        const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[1];
        const rows = await sheet.getRows({
            query:'Clan = clan-12'
        });
        // rows = rows.map(a => a._rawData)
        rows.forEach(row =>{
             printStudent(row);
         });
      
     
    })()

function printStudent(data){
    console.log(data.Clan);
    console.log(data.SheetId);
    console.log(data.Enabled);
}
```

I have searched the whole documentation but not able to get any idea on why it is not working? the googlespreed sheet api version is 4.0 and node js library of google spreedsheet is latest 3.1.15. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. I cannot understand about `For example in my cell D2 I wish to pass parameters which will select on ly that id and will not bring the rest of data.`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? 2. I cannot understand your current issue from `But my code is not working.` I apologize for this again. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Comment: @Tanaike No issues I apologize that I was not able to explain clearly. Look what I want to do is just like we use select query I only wish to select a row where SheetID value is equal to the parameter I have passed. I don't wish to return the whole json array just a singe record like we usually do with other db such as mysql etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal and current situation as follows.

- You want to retrieve the rows by searching a value using the query like `select * from db where id = ""`.
- You are using a library of "google-spreadsheet". [Ref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet)
- You have already been able to get and put values using Sheets API with "google-spreadsheet".

#### Modification points:

- In the current stage, the search query cannot be directly used with Sheets API. So in this case, it is required to use a workaround. In this answer, I would like to propose the workaround.
- In this workaround, the Query Language for Spreadsheet is used with "google-spreadsheet". So, the access token is retrieved from the authorization script of "google-spreadsheet".

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, please set the variables. In this sample script, the ID is searched from the column "A" of the 2nd tab in Google Spreadsheet. If you want to search the ID from other column, please modify `query`.

```
const { GoogleSpreadsheet } = require("google-spreadsheet");
const request = require("request");
// const csvParse = require("csv-parse"); // If you want to retrieve the values an array, please use this.

const creds = require("../credentialfile.json");  // Please set your credential file of the service account.

async function main() {
  const id = "sampleId"; // Please set the search text. In your case, it's ID.
  const query = `select * where A='${id}'`; // This is the query for searching.
  const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.

  const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(spreadsheetId);
  await doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds);
  await doc.loadInfo();
  const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[1]; // It seems that in your script, the ID is searched from the 2nd tab in Spreadsheet.
  const url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${spreadsheetId}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&gid=${sheet.sheetId}&tq=${encodeURI(query)}`;
  request(
    {
      url: url,
      method: "GET",
      headers: {authorization: `Bearer ${doc.jwtClient.credentials.access_token}`},
    },
    (err, res, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      console.log(result);
      // if (result != "") csvParse(result, {}, (err, ar) => console.log(ar));  // If you want to retrieve the values an array, please use this.
    }
  );
}

main();
```

#### Reference:

- [Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)